# Date formatting in jquery ? dd-mm-yy to dd-M-Y

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I am trying to write down a generic function for my project which returns the date format something like `dd-M-y` i.e  `10-dec-14` .

Normally i pass input to function parameter as date of format `dd-mm-yy` and trying to convert back to my required format .

```
    Function Format(dateval) `04-12-2014`
    {
//Trail 1 :
    var newdate = new Date(dateval); `o/p: 12 April 2014` like that its getting converted which is way wrong 

//Trail 2 :
var newdate = $.DatePicker('dd-M-Y',dateval); `o/p: 12-04-2014`

//Trail 3 : Splitting date and compare and build format manually 

return newdate;

    }
```

Its been a hell of experience using `new Date` which acts weird many ways something like `13-20-2014` gives `jan 20th 2014` phew i can't explain my troubles .

I'm looking for a serious fix on this which does my job in a prolific way .

**PS:** I'm not a huge fan of plugins . Please don't dig those for my problem .

**{EDIT:1}**

**Possible Solution :** Done some digging with reference to answer by [**Rob post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512476/get-javascript-date-formatted-as-2011-04-01) and [**this**](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) wonderful article . Credits to `Clint Powell` for his help .

```
(function() {
    var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  function fetch(n) {
    return n<10? '0'+n : ''+n;
  }
    function output(dat){
    var d = new Date(dat.replace(/(\d+)([-\/\\\.])(\d+)/, "$3$2$1"));
        return fetch(d.getDate())+'-'+months[d.getMonth()]+'-'+(d.getFullYear()+'').slice(-2);}
    window.output=output; //exposes the output function outside
}());
```

Functional fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/jdkkruap/4/)

*Advantage:* 
Best fit if we are trying to do something generic and use in many places

Any suggestion on this is much appreciated

Comment: Are you against just doing the conversion manually? It wouldn't take many lines of code.

Comment: oh guys common enough sarcasm to down vote . i'm pretty sure i am clear about my question . cheers .

Comment: Dates and times can be tricky.  Even though you mentioned you don't want plugins, you might consider adding a date library (like [http://momentjs.com/](momentjs)) and let it take care of the date formatting for you.  Then you can avoid thinking about things like timezones and daylight savings and leap years.

Comment: @ClintPowell it will do it but in a hard way right mate where there is always a chance of code breaking . can you walk me through your approach ?

Comment: @mrrogers i been using knockout with jquery but if i use this moment.js which will be a issue for me as i already tried this wonderful plugin . for display thumbs up but other way it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple way to do what you want. It's just a custom method. Sometimes it's best to take a simple homemade solution. http://jsfiddle.net/jdkkruap/6/

```
function customDate(d, monthFirst) {
    if(!(d instanceof Date)) {
        !monthFirst ? d = new Date(d.replace(/(\d+)([-\/\\\.])(\d+)/, "$3$2$1")) : d = new Date(d);
    }
    var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];
    return (d.getDate() > 9 ? d.getDate() : "0"+d.getDate()) +'-'+months[d.getMonth()]+'-'+(d.getFullYear()+"").substr(2)
}
```

Now you can call the method as follows:

```
customDate('10-12-2014');       //output will be 10-dec-14
customDate('10-12-2014', true); //output will be 12-oct-14
```

If you really want flexibility, consider using moment.js: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: as per my question i am looking for 10-12-2014 to '10-dec-2014' . i f i am not wrong i mentioned that above haven't i ?

Comment: I understand what you mean now, give me just a moment (no pun intended). Your problem is that the day comes first, month comes second (like many European date formats). Is that the way all your dates will be passed in?

Comment: bingo yes mate . you got me now i believe

Comment: so sorry to bring it up i wrongly mentioned in my comment i.e i need year as `14` not 2014

Comment: i fixed the issue mate used `slice(-2)` . thanks mate